# Linq query too slow

Tags: c#, linq

I've set up the following linq query in C#.  The CompDotPinNamePinDict dictionary is of type `<string, object>` and the object has a `List<string>` called UniqueNetNames.

I'm building a a collection of device pins on a PCB that we call a net.  A net is essentially a wire that connects the device pins together.

The average pin dictionary will contain about 80k entries.
The average UniqueNetName list will contain about 4 entries.

Here is my code surrounding the linq query:

```
var uniqueName = dr[0].ToString().ToUpper().Trim();

//Get all of the pins with the associated net names

// BUG - Following .Contains() is 37% of import processing time. Needs optimized.
var values = DataStore.OriginalSolution.CompDotPinNamePinDic.Where(x => uniqueName == x.Key ||
                x.Value.UniqueNetNames.Contains(uniqueName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

foreach (var pin in values)
{
    newNet.AddPin(pin.Value);
}

//If no pins were found, alert the user
if(!newNet.PinListDic.Any())
{
    errors.Add("SRTool:Missing pins in " + newNet.UniqueNetName + "(FFI Net Name). Net not created.");
    continue;
}
```

Afterward, I take the list of pins `values` and continue creating my `net`.  Of all of my import functionality, 49.7% of my processor time is spent on the above linq query.

Can anybody think of a better way to extract a set of pins from this dictionary?

Comment: You may need to add an index to your DB. Contain queries really don't perform well, so you should try to rewrite using a equals and have an index on that column

Comment: If UniqueNetNames contains Uniq values - then use HashSet<string> instead of List<string>. List's Contains method iterates for all values and compare every string, which is very slow.

Comment: I set up some sample data, with 80k records, and 4 `UniqeNetNames` entries for each record, and your query took only 304 milliseconds. Is that the kind of speed you are getting?

Comment: But how long does it take? 50% of cpu time being spent there doesn't mean it's slow, no matter what 100% will have to be spent "somewhere", how slow is it in milliseconds?

Comment: Simply swapping the comparisons around (uniqueName == x.Key before the .Contains) may make a slight difference as you're performing the lighter comparison first. You'll have to benchmark that though as it will depend on your data.

Comment: Can you try profiling again after adding a `.ToArray()` to the end of the query please?

Comment: Switching the list of uniquenetnames to HashSet<string> increased the Delta by 2.35 (Performance Exporer Comparison)

ToArray() at the end of the query increased the Delta by 15.3 points and added time to process the ToArray().

Comment: Ronan - I can't seem to find out how to see the processing time as opposed to percentage. Let me keep researching this and I'll post an answer as soon as I figure it out.

Comment: If adding `.ToArray()` increased the performance it sounds like you are doing minimal processing of the values after the query. I think you need to post more of the surrounding code. Actually the query, as you've posted it, uses deferred execution so it is only executed by the code after it anyway. You need to post that code.

Comment: Why not `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` ?

Comment: I added the surrounding code.  dr[0] is a row from a DataTable. Column zero is the net name that we need to assemble and the other columns are values imported later and added to that net after we have added all of the required pins.

Comment: andleer, from my research, use a `Dictionary` only reduces overhead for larger amounts of data and `List<>` is faster for my code because there are only 5 or less values stored in it.  In testing with running the `List<string>` as a `Dictionary<string, string>` and then modifying all of my code to read the Key so that it would compile, it added 1.9 seconds to make my total processing time 27.48s.

I tracked the total processing time by adding a `Timer` to start before BackgroundRunner launches and then stop after it completes.  For Ronan, I'll go add the timer around the specific linq query.